# Primefaces datatable sorting a list

Tags: sorting, user-interface, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have a datatable in Primefaces which has sorting feature on click of column header, when I click on sort it sorts like this example
Existing output:

```
        APPLE
        ORANGE
        ZEN
        apple
        orange
        zen
```

I would like the sort output to be like this on UI

```
        APPLE
        apple
        ORANGE
        orange
        ZEN
        zen
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Existing code:

```
                    <p:column id="firstName" 
                        sortBy="#{row.user.firstName}"
                        filterBy="#{row.user.firstName}"
                        styleClass="col-left" 
                        filterStyleClass="filter-full">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{appmsg['first.name']}" />
                        </f:facet>

                        <h:outputText value="#{row.user.firstName}" />
                    </p:column>
```

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using? from 5.0.1 filtering is case insensitive

Comment: @MangO_O: filtering != sorting

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces has the option to plugin a custom sortFunction, see the documentation of the [Datatable](https://speakerdeck.com/player/827b32202f6f01321c076e02156363ec?slide=149#) and Column

You can then sort whatever way you want. And if you use a LazyDatamodel, you have even more control.